What is purpose of ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose in a riverpod flutter and how to use it?
I am a newbie in a flutter State Management and i am also willing to learn Riverpod state Management and i am learning it step by step.
What is a purpose of ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose in a riverpod flutter
Any help would be highly appreciated in advance
Thanks
